# TPL + C++/CLI: tutorials, samples

Tags: c++-cli, task-parallel-library

Is it possible to use TPL in C++/CLI?
Major materials I find relate to PPL, not TPL. If I try to use TPL as I used for C# (e.g. retrieving result of an async operation, via `->Result`), then get something like

> Error  150 error C2039: 'Result' : is not a member of 'System::Threading::Tasks::Task`1'

Any samples or good tutorials? Thanks

Comment: `task->Result` works just fine for me. Could you show us your code? Also, I doubt you will find any good tutorials, because C++/CLI is not used very often, except for some specific tasks (like interop).

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to post a code snippet so your problem is pretty undiagnosable.  Be sure to use `Task<TResult>` to have a Result property.  This sample code compiled and ran without trouble.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#using <System.Core.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading::Tasks;

ref class SomeTask {
public:
    static int run() {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Task<int>^ task = Task<int>::Factory->StartNew(gcnew Func<int>(&SomeTask::run));
    task->Wait();
    Console::WriteLine(task->Result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you much for your input. Indeed, no signs that TPL should not work with cpp/CLI. I've digged more and found out that the compiler 'Platform toolset' parameter was set to v90 instead of v100 (I've been porting the project from 3.5 to 4.0). That was the reason.